# NSPredicate Differences

Tags: swift3, nspredicate

I have been teaching myself predicates and I have a situation with differing behavior between two predicates that should act the same.

This first case works correctly, returning some items:

```
let wordPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] 'word'")
(items as NSArray).filtered(using: wordPredicate)
```

bet the second case does not return anything:

```
let keyContainsVarPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "$key CONTAINS[cd] '$word'")
(items as NSArray).filtered(using: keyContainsVarPredicate.withSubstitutionVariables(["key": "name", "word": "word"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out actually.

You cannot substitute in you property name.